# My Elements Are Overlapping When Window Size Reduces

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got these boxes that pop up that's fine its when the screen size reduces they start overlapping each other.  I would like to keep constant spacing between the boxes and stop text from running out the box is this possible?[image: Normal Screen Size],[image: Smaller Screen Size],[image: Even Smaller Screen Size]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `min-width` CSS Property to prevent overlapping.

**For Instance,**

```
#abc, .abc{
    min-width:800px;
    }
```

> The min-width property allow authors to constrain content widths to a certain range.

**[SOURCE](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/min-width)**

What the above example does is that if your window for instance reaches a minimum width of 800px, it gives you a horizontal scrollbar at the bottom which fits your content to a minimum range of 800px.

Hope this helps.

*PS: #abc, .abc is a dummy name for the div id or class that you have for which you need to set the min-width to prevent overlap. You can replace this with your id or class. Similarly 800px is an illustrative value which you can replace with your desired window width.*